How can I add multiple or conditions in an if statement in powerbi?
I was to create a custom column B which groups values in column A.
I had it as something like this:
if [A]='DA1' or [A]='DA2' or [A]='DA3' then [B]='group1' 
else if [A]='SA1' or [A]='DA4' or [A] = 'FA5' then [B]='group2'
else [B]='other'

but it seems very long winded
I'm trying to get from this:



A




DA1


DA2


DA3


DA4


DA5


FA5


SA1


FA6


PL2



to:

I have five groups in total, but wanted to know if there was a quicker way of writing multiple a multiple or for each group.
Thanks!

Check out the SWITCH function and using IN.
DAX
B = SWITCH(TRUE(),
  [A] in { "DA1", "DA2", "DA3" }, "group1",
  [A] in { "DA4", "DA5", "FA5", "SA1" }, "group2",
  "other"
)

Update
Apologies, I wrongly assumed you were wanting DAX.
For Power Query, what you have is okay. You may prefer:
Power Query
if List.Contains( { "DA1", "DA2", "DA3" }, [A]) then "group1" else
if List.Contains( { "DA4", "DA5", "FA5", "SA1" }, [A]) then "group2"
else "other"

An alternative approach would be to have a Query (table) with the following:



Key
Group




DA1
group1


DA2
group1


DA3
group1


DA4
group2


DA5
group2


FA5
group2


SA1
group2



And then do a Merge and Expand.
For the other, you can either add all the keys to that table, or replace value null to 'other' after the Merge and Expand.
